# Swift/Alamofire/ObjectMapper: Ignore nil values

Tags: swift, alamofire, alamofireobjectmapper

Just wondering if this is possible as I am trying to avoid creating duplicate/very similar models.

If for example I have the following JSON:

```
{ 
  "1001": {
    "first_name": "James",
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "age": 30,
  }
  "1002": {
    "first_name": "Sarah",
    "last_name": "Jones",
  }
}
```

And I have the following class to map the user data:

```
class UserModel: Mappable {

  var firstName: String?
  var lastName: String?
  var age: Int?

  required init?(map: Map) {}

  func mapping(map: Map) {
      start           <- map["first_name"]
      current         <- map["last_name"]
      stage           <- map["age"]
  }

}
```

This works perfectly, apart from if I print out the response, I would get the following:

```
{
  {
    "firstName" : "James",
    "lastName"  : "Smith",
    "age"       : 30
  }
  {
    "firstName" : "Sarah",
    "lastName"  : "Jones",
    "age"       : nil
  }
}
```

Is there a way to ignore any `nil` values while the request is being made? Trying to avoid having to create another `UserModel` which the age removed, and would rather keep a single model but just ignore keys that I know would not appear in the response.

Comment: being `1001"` isn't valid either `1001` or `"1001"` then `[Int:Model]` or `[String:Model]` respectively

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Codable` instead

```
struct Model : Codable {
  let firstName,lastName:String
  let age:Int?
}
```

---

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase 
let res = try? decoder.decode([String:Model].self,from:data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
struct UserModelValue: Codable, Equatable {
    let firstName: String?
    let lastName: String?
    let age: Int?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case firstName = "first_name"
        case lastName = "last_name"
        case age = "age"
    }

    init(firstName: String?, lastName: String?, age: Int?) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.age = age
    }
}

typealias UserModel = [String: UserModelValue]
```